# Can't strikethrough text that has string interpolation?

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to add a bullet point preceding my subtask text and then add a strikethrough it. The problem is, if I use string interpolation and precede my subtask name with anything, the strikethrough does not display. However if I set the button title to just my subtask name and try to strikethrough, it works.

```
subtaskButton.setTitle("- \(subtask.name)", for: .normal)
strikethrough(text: subtask.name, label: subtaskButton.titleLabel!)

private func strikethrough(text: String, label: UILabel) {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        label.attributedText = attributedString
    }
```

^ Does not work

```
subtaskButton.setTitle("\(subtask.name)", for: .normal)
subtaskButton.setTitle(subtask.name, for: .normal)
```

^ Both of these work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `setAttributedTitle(_:for:)` instead of setting the `attributedText` of the label directly.

```
private func strikethrough(text: String, button: UIButton) {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
}
```